# Rails STi with 1 to 1 association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have 2 existing models, that I would want to create a 1 to 1 association. My only issue is these 2 models inherit from the same parent class

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

class Student < Model
  #has one :info


class Info < Model
  #belongs to :student
```

How do I create the migration for this?

Comment: This seems, possibly, like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I agree with @lacostenycoder that `Model` seems like a peculiar name to use. And, it's not totally obvious (to me at least) that `Student` and `Info` are semantically similar - so why use STI? Also, you don't state what the "issue" is. And what exactly you're trying to create a migration *for*.

Comment: we don't know enough about your models and relations to give a good answer.  1 to 1 doesn't tell the whole story. Please provide more details.

Comment: Can you explain why you need STI here? Why store `students` and `info` in the same table?

Answer (score 0):

From https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

```
rails generate migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references
```

> generates

```
class AddUserRefToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :products, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

> This migration will create a user_id column and appropriate index. For more add_reference options, visit the API documentation.

So in your case:

```
rails generate migration AddStudentRefToInfo student:references
```

Which will generate the following migration:

```
class AddUserRefToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :info, :student, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Note that assumes your 'Info' model is stored in a table called 'info'. It might be 'infos'.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. but I am using a single table inheritance, that is only Model is saved in the database. Theres just a type field in model to distinguish it from student or info

Comment: Your answer is trying to solve an XY problem as mentioned in the comments, see http://xyproblem.info/  but so is mine I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use Model as a model name? I think what you're looking for is polymorphic relation https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

But without more information about your models we can't provide the best answer.
You  might want to have a look at [this article on STI vs Polymorphic relations](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: Link to "article on STI vs Polymorphic relations" does not seem right.